# How to update a python library without restarting ipynb kernel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, numpy, sys

Unfortunately, there is no better way to do this, so please don't ask why I can't do it the normal way, it is too long to explain :). The issue is that one of the packages demands numpy<=1.21, but the one installed is 1.23.4 . In the notebook I run `!pip install numpy==1.21` which solves the issue, BUT pip tells you that to see the changes you have to restart the notebook (which I cannot do). I think that is because the notebook runs in a virtual environment and numpy is installed outside of it. I have tried many things like `%%reboot` or `importlib.reload(np)`, but the output of

```
import numpy as np

print(np.__version__)
```

Is strictly 1.23.4 . Maybe there is a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I often use the line magics

```py
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

At the start of the notebook to allow for incremental development of a library. Maybe that will work on this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work in my case, but otherwise this is a cool feature, thanks for sharing